# Using mpirun -np X with tensorflow: is X limited by the number of GPUs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mpi, gpu

I'm trying to use mpi with TensorFlow. For an example of such a code, [see this OpenAI baselines PPO code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/ppo1). It tells us to run the following command:

```
$ mpirun -np 8 python -m baselines.ppo1.run_atari
```

I have a machine with one GPU (with 12GB of RAM) and Tensorflow 1.3.0 installed, with Python 3.5.3. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
2017-09-24 17:29:12.975967: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN X (Pascal)
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.531
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.90GiB
Free memory: 11.17GiB
2017-09-24 17:29:12.975990: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-09-24 17:29:12.975996: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-09-24 17:29:12.976011: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-09-24 17:29:12.987133: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN X (Pascal)
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.531
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.90GiB
Free memory: 11.17GiB
2017-09-24 17:29:12.987159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-09-24 17:29:12.987165: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-09-24 17:29:12.987172: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
[2017-09-24 17:29:12,994] Making new env: PongNoFrameskip-v4
2017-09-24 17:29:13.017845: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-09-24 17:29:13.022347: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: TITAN X (Pascal)
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.531
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 11.90GiB
Free memory: 104.81MiB
2017-09-24 17:29:13.022394: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-09-24 17:29:13.022415: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-09-24 17:29:13.022933: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-09-24 17:29:13.026338: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:924] failed to allocate 104.81M (109903872 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

(This is only the first part of the error message; it's extremely long, but I think this beginning part is the important thing to see.)

This command works, though, if I run with `mpirun -np 1`.

I searched online, and I found a [repository from Uber](https://github.com/uber/horovod) which says that "To run on a machine with 4 GPUs" I need to use:

```
$ mpirun -np 4 python train.py
```

I just want to confirm that `mpirun -np X` means that `X` is limited by the number of GPUs on the machine, assuming that what we're running is a TensorFlow program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading more about MPI, I can confirm that yes, indeed the number of processes is limited by the number of GPUs. Rationale:

- The `mpirun -np X` command will run X "copies" of the code (but each with its own rank). [See the documentation here](http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/introMPI.html).
- Each run of the code needs a GPU
- TensorFlow only allows one program to use one GPU at once. In other words, you can't run `python tf_program1.py` and `python tf_program2.py` simultaneously while both of them use TensorFlow and require the lone GPU on your machine.

Thus it looks like I'm forced to use one process.